# SQL query won't work can't figure out why

Tags: php, sql, select

In a timetracking application I'm developing right now this query fails and I can't figure out why. The Var $userID has the value 1 in it what is right. The naming of each table and field should be correct because I checked it like four times.

query:

```
$query= 'SELECT arbeiter.id AS id,'.                                
        'tblMitarbeiterUUID.dtLastname AS dtLastname, ' .
        'tblMitarbeiterUUID.dtFirstname AS dtFirstname, ' .
        'FROM arbeiter, tblMitarbeiterUUID ' .
        'WHERE ' .
        'arbeiter.id =' . $userID .' ' .
        'AND arbeiter.start_date < NOW() '.                                         
        'AND (arbeiter.end_date=\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\" '.
        'OR arbeiter.end_date > NOW())';
```

If I echo the Query I get this:

```
SELECT arbeiter.id AS id,tblMitarbeiterUUID.dtLastname AS dtLastname, tblMitarbeiterUUID.dtFirstname AS dtFirstname, FROM arbeiter, tblMitarbeiterUUID WHERE arbeiter.id =1 AND arbeiter.start_date < NOW() AND (arbeiter.end_date=\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\" OR arbeiter.end_date > NOW())
```

The error I get when trying to paste query directly into my sql tool:

> SQL syntax error near :"FROM arbeiter, tblMitarbeiterUUID WHERE arbeiter.id =1 AND arbeiter.start_date <"

I bet it should be an easy fix for one of you guys. Or is my approach to this wrong and should I try it with an INNER JOIN ?

Thanks in advance

**ERRORS found the comma after dtFirstname and the backslashes to escape the " were the problems! Now everything works fine.**

Comment: Voted to close as this is mainly just a typo.  BUT you also link to a table called `tblMitarbeiterUUID` which has no mention in the where clause - may be what you want not sure.

Comment: the where clause should stay this way I only need the first and lastname to set the var $username in the code below

Comment: As the SQL is in single quotes, there is no need to escape the quotes in `\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\"`,so remove both of the `\\`'s.

Comment: THAT WAS IT ! Thanks alot will close this question now. Very happy for the fast and competent help !

Comment: There is a comma between dtFirstname and FROM, just delete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a little syntax error with redundant comma `,` at the end.

```
'tblMitarbeiterUUID.dtFirstname AS dtFirstname, '
```

Change it to:

```
'tblMitarbeiterUUID.dtFirstname AS dtFirstname'
```

Comment: Thanks alot  I thought it only was a small thing. I removed the comma but I still get a syntax error :"near \"0000-00-00 00:00:00\" OR arbeiter.end_date > NOW())"

Comment: removing the backslash for escaping the " has solved the problem